# Altium not showing all 3D models, expect when in import changes dialog box

Tags: pcb-design, altium, 3d

I got all models loaded and made sure that I was not hiding anything in "View Configuration" or that all my opacities are set at a 100%.
Most 3D bodies show up, however some are missing.

Two things :

- If I manually place a component in PCB view, the 3D model of this component will show up, however not the exact same component that was loaded from the schematics. See first picture
- If I open the "Design > Import changes from [Project Name]", while in the dialog, all models show up. See second picture

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if a component has been edited in the library, but has not been refreshed in the schematic editor, ie the schematic still thinks it has the *old* symbol. When placed directly into the PCB, libraries are up to date.

In your PCB, right-click on a component and select `Component Actions` > `Updated Selected Components from PCB Libraries`

[image]

This will check for differences and perform an ECO that you can accept. If there is a difference, the action would be to `modify`, which you can accept, or `execute`

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention I have already tried this on many separate occasions with no results.